# Proof that the infinite series converges: $\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^{\ln i}}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I need to proof that the following infinite series converges:

$$\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^{\ln i}}$$

My first idea is to compare it to $\frac{1}{i^{2}}$, since $i^{\ln i} > i^2$ for big $i$. And $\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^2}$ converges, so $\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^{\ln i}}$ should converge as well.

But I not sure if this is a valid argument, because I am not sure if I can use this comparison when the exponent is $\ln i$ and not a constant.

Can someone, please, tell me if my argument is valid and if not, what is the correct argument I should use.

Comment: Of course it is irrelevant whether the exponent is a constant or not.

Comment: Are your saying that I can not compare it to $\frac{1}{n^2}$?

Comment: @xbh is saying that you _can_ compare it.

Comment: Ok. So my argument is valid. Right?

Comment: Yes, it's valid. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: When in doubt, work with partial sums. What bounds can you place on $\sum_{i=2}^n\frac{1}{i^{\ln i}}$?

Comment: @J.G., this seems like a very good advice. Could you please expand it in a answer?

Comment: Your sequence of partial sums is bounded above by $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2} = \pi^2/6$ and increasing.

Comment: Oh maybe not bounded above by $\pi^2/6$ as the first six terms don't satisfy $\ln i \geq 2$, but the sequence of partial sums is still bounded above by a constant